# Continuous bijective function between $\Bbb{R}$ and $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Does a continuous bijective function from $\Bbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$ exist? If not please explain. Here $[0,1]$ and $\Bbb{R}$ have the usual topology.

Comment: To be clear, you’re not asking for the inverse function to be continuous, right?

Comment: That is correct, I think I've figured it out though.

Comment: @user140506: at least a continuous bijective function from $[0,1]$ to $\bf R$ doesn't exist because a continuous bijective function from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Injective continuous functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ must be monotone.

Answer (score 1):

By the intermediate value theorem, continuous injective functions are either increasing or decreasing. Hence $f[\mathbb{R}]$ can not have a maximum or minimum.

Comment: Oh, $\arctan$ is unbounded?

Comment: @TedShifrin Fixed

Comment: Yeah, better. I guess we posted simultaneously. I really would rather have left it for the OP to figure it out from just my hint.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions on a closed interval must be necessarily bounded . This arises from the definition of continuity at a point $c$:  $\forall \epsilon>0 , \exists \delta>0 $ such that $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$

i.e. $f(c) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(c) + \epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$

Since the given interval is closed, it's possible to divide the interval to a number of intervals and find out the range of functional value at the points in each of the interval. Hence, in this way, we can find out the minima and maxima

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little misguided in my reasoning, but I would argue that by the Heine-Borel theorem, [0,1] is compact and the continuous image of a compact set is also compact. The real numbers in their entirety, as you do want your function to be surjective, are unbounded and hence non-compact. Thus, no such continuous function exists.

Comment: That is an argument why there is no continuous bijection whose domain is $[0,1]$ onto $\Bbb R$. But the question is concerned with the opposite direction. Note also that the inverse of a continuous bijection need not be continuous itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila my mistake, I must have misread the question.